# Can't generate new module in angular - Invalid rule result: Function()

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I am working in angular.
I want to generate new module. I am using this command: **`ng g m --name moduleName --routing`**.
But I am getting this error: **`Invalid rule result: Function()`**.

[image]

Anyone can suggest what should I do now.

Comment: can you just try `ng g m moduleName --routing`

Comment: @Kirubel That gives me this error: *`Data path "" should have required property 'name'`*

Comment: can you include your version of `angular-cli` and what IDE you're using on

Comment: Refresh the question, I have edited it.

Comment: Have you check version of angular cli and angular schematic... ?

Comment: You should try this @angular-devkit/schematics@0.7.0 version of schematic for angular cli 6.0.8

Comment: @mayurkukadiya Yes, you can see it in image.

Comment: bro you must use `ng g m yourModuleName --routing`

Answer (score 1):

After `@Mayur-kukadiya's` suggestion I got the answer and solve my problem..

> First I update my `schematics` by run this command : **`npm install @schematics/angular@0.6.8 --save-dev`**

After I run this command for generate module: **`ng g m --name moduleName --routing`** .